# Combining mongodb and mysql data for view

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a decently big ecommerce project with MySQL as DB Server at present. Due to increasing complexity of catalog architecture, I am evaluating MongoDB as DB Server choice for managing products and other catalog data. Rest of data like orders will be managed through MySQL only.

Now, if customer place an order. Then order will contain information of both products bought and order info. In MySQL it is simple as making a join. But what if catalog and orders are managed in different DB, how can I store and pull this data together to show on view?

One solution that I thought of is to create one table in MySQL, which holds basic info of a product and unique id of document of same product in MongoDB. But this will result in data duplication and also another challenge to keeping consistency will emerge.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Check out $lookup, which SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: No I am not looking for join between MongoDB documents, but between data contained in MongoDB and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll be very efficient as it'll make your application very chatty. Assuming your data is shared among both mongo and mysql, every time a request is initiated, you need to send two queries (one to mongo and one to mysql). Then your program has to do all the validation and merge the data from two databases and then report it to customer. This will only increase the latency and you'll not be able to utilize the full performance of both databases. I would suggest, better maintain your data in any one of the database

Comment: I can not maintain orders data in MongoDb due to critical writes and transactions involved in its procedure. Hence order management system data should reside in MySQL